# Google Map API - Plan selection

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api

We are planning to develop a web based application for one of the Research Institute.

Overview of the application:

1. It is survey application
2. It requires login credentials for data-entry operator to open web-app for collecting participant’s information
3. It has fixed number of login credentials for data-entry operators (No user registration)
4. Google Maps APIs will be used in this application for locating and collecting participant’s address details (Places Search APIs and
   Reverse Geo coding)

We have gone through the following links

1. https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/
2. https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

As this application will be used by Research Institute, We are not sure which plan (Standard/Premium) can be used for such type of application.

Also we are not able to connect with Sales team where we can evaluate the application for correct billing plan.

We need help on following items

1. Identifying correct plan/package for pricing and legal terms as the customer is a research institute
2. How can we connect to direct Googles' sales team for clarifying or identifying correct plan as there is no direct support available except for Premium plan?

Answer (score 0):

After different searches (googling) and connects found below URL to connect with Google Support team for Map API queries

https://enterprise.google.com/intl/en_in/maps/contact-form/

**Note:** *We got response from google support team after aprox. 7 days. So expect minimum 7 days for response.*

Hope this would help to someone having similar query.

Thanks!